# How to obtain the "Crab Rave" badge in Bloons Pop! -?

Tags: mobile, bloons-pop

There's a hidden badge named "Crab Rave" (Unlocked the secrets of the sea) in *Bloons Pop!*. How is it obtained?

The [Bloons Wiki](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Hidden_Achievements) just gives its description with no further details.

I happen to catch someone with this badge on a leaderboard.

[image]